# How to set cookies for mutiple pages with getServerSideProps

Tags: cookies, next.js

In my application i’m getting the users IP address and then timezone on the server in getserversideprops in order to display user specific content and keep the SEO benefits of server side rendering.

On every page of the site my serversideprops looks like:

```
    // check if timezone cookie exists
    // if not, get ip and timezone
    // set timezone cookie
    // use cookie to retrieve user specific data and return in props
```

It works fine but it doesn’t feel right writing duplicate code like that and having it on every page.

Is there a way to set/retrieve the cookies in _app.js or something similar to context but for the server?

Comment: fot this situation we use next build-in `middlewares`

Comment: @MoeinMoeinnia if i use middleware is the cookie available for me to use in getserversideprops?

Comment: i haven't tested it personally but it must be ok. u can set cookie in middleware and check in `getServerSideProps( )` if the cookie was set or not